# Receiving Empty DataFrame output hen scraping html table in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble scraping this table with pandas. I tried accessing the table I want using the table's id tag, but it only returned the header column and says there's an empty data frame. If anyone has any ideas it would greatly be appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url_1 = 'https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/mlb/batter-vs-pitcher-stats?
date=2011-09-27'
df1 = pd.read_html(url_1,attrs={'id': ['stat-table']})
print(df1)
```

The code's output:
[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Batter, Pitcher, PA, AB, H, 1B, 2B, 3B, HR, BB, SO, AVG, OBP, SLG, PPpA]
Index: []]

---

(program exited with code: 0)

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: real data not in `stat-table`. It is filled-in by json from `this.playerArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you carefully inspect the page's source, you will notice that the information is contained in `this.playerArray`, so if you want to get all the data, something along the following lines should do the job:

```
import requests

page = requests.get('https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/mlb/batter-vs-pitcher-stats?%20date=2011-09-27')

start = page.text.find('this.playerArray = ') + 19
end = page.text.find("this.currentSite = 'default';")

data = eval(page.text[start:end].replace(';', '').replace('\n', ''))
```

...the data will be in a list of dicts, each row being a separate dict.

You may want to later use pandas (for instance, `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict()`) if you want it in a DataFrame, or something.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at the elements tab through the inspect button on google chrome and it made it look like a simple html table.